# How to use either endroid camera or emulator camera to record a specific portion of screen?

Tags: android-emulator, android-camera, tiktok

Essentially I'm wondering if there is a way to use either a IRL phone camera or an emulator to record a portion of a computer screen or have it so that the camera sees that portion of the computer screen? So essentially tiktok has it so it can only go live from the phones camera, I'm wondering if there is a way  to emulate a portion of my computer screen through the camera itself so that tiktok sees this as a real camera. I was trying to do some programing streams and honestly you can't really read the text with my phone setup above my shoulder so to say the least it leaves the viewers wanting... so im just wondering what can be done? And is there an emulator the directs the camera to the computer screen?

I've tried looking around and found loola, but that seems to break the stream its self on tiktoks side where you don't make it to the for you page...